# Starter Questions for Using Git Windows Version with Git Source Control Provider

Tags: windows, git, svn, github, tortoisesvn

I was using "Tortoisesvn" to take control of my programs's source code. But sometimes, I had problems/bugs while using it. So I decided to use "git"( http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/ ) Also, I'm using git with "Git Source Control Provider" visual studio plugin. Source control is very easy with this extension.

So now I have few noob questions...

1) Where is the main repository? Where is the folder that my project's files backup?

2) Is this program working completely offline? I mean how secure is that? Are there any changes that someone can steal your files( repository/source codes etc. ) ?

Thanks for any input*
Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is different from SVN in that Git is a DVCS - Distributed Version Control System. That means every "working copy" is a full blown repo. Repos can talk to themselves and there is no need for a main repository ( but usually there is a main or "blessed" repo that is the central.)

So when you created a Git "working copy", you created a repo. You setup another repo on different maching / server and push to it if needed.

I don't know what you mean by "backup", but the metadate for git will be under the `.git` folder ( it will be hidden unless you have selected to show hidden files and folders in Explorer)

Another feature of DVCS that results from having full blown repos and no main repos is that it works offline. You get full history and you can commit without contacting any server etc. Again, I don't understand why you would ask about security in this context? If it is offline, wouldn't that be the most secure? And Git has lots of security and integrity mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't work with a centralized "main" repository. Each repo is considered an equal to every other repo.

Git can work completely offline (unlike some other source control systems), but in order to push changes to other repositories you'll of course need to be connected in some way to the machine where the remote repo is hosted.